# Comparing read lines to the regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm planning on read a *.cpp file and I would like to compare each read line against a regex. I.e.

```
# include <iostream>
```

I'd like to check if this line starts with # excluding any whitespace etc, is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Something like `#.*\S` I do believe.

Comment: @AJG85 how would you read that? Hash followed by anything 0 or more times... and how is the \S fitting? and what if line doesn't start with hash but with few spaces? would your pattern work?

Comment: `#` is a literal `.*` is 0 or more of anything else `\S` is Perl shorthand for "not whitespace" ... you can use `[^[:space:]]` for a Posix compliant "not whitespace"

Comment: You can quicly test / experiment regexps using online tools: ex.: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is to check that the first non-space character of a line is `#` that should work:

```
^\s*#
```

- `^` anchor regexp to the the beginning of the line so you start checking it from the first character
- `\s` stands for space symbol (spaces, tabs, and line breaks)
- `*` means zero or more repetition of previous character (space in that case)
- `#` to make sure that first symbol after sequence (may be empty) of spaces is `#`

How you'll use that regexp depends on what language you're going to use for reading and parsing that file.